# Block All Traffic and Allow from Defined IP only in IPTABLES

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, routing, iptables

I want to create a gateway firewall for my network  . I want to block all the internal traffic on gateway and allow it from two  computers only .
On gateway

--> eth0 is network card in gateway PC that connects to the Internet

--> eth1 is network card in gateway PC that connects to my internal network

I want to accept traffic from only two ip from internal network and forward them from eth0 to main internet and block all rest traffic.

```
Allow ip 192.168.10.25 and 192.168.10.14
```

My rules are as follows.

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP 
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP    
iptables -P FORWARD DROP    
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.10.25 -j ACCEPT    
iptables -I INPUT -s 192.168.10.14 -j ACCEPT    
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.10.25 -j ACCEPT    
iptables -I OUTPUT -s 192.168.10.14 -j ACCEPT

iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE    
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth1 -j ACCEPT

echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Please any one can correct my rules .

Comment: Perhaps you should tell us what is not working for you

Comment: Perhaps you mean `-d` for destination (instead of `-s` for source) on the two `OUTPUT` rules?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply rules to the FORWARD chain:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.10.25 -j ACCEPT    
iptables -I FORWARD -s 192.168.10.14 -j ACCEPT
```

I suspect you would like to accept the response:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```